# 'no module' error with __init__.py in directory using Nosetests

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-module

I have the following directory structure:

```
Chippa/

      bin/
         __init__.py
         app.py

      tests/
         __init__.py
         app_tests.py
         tools.py

      templates/
         hello_form.html
         index.html
         layout.html

      docs/
```

In my `app_tests.py` file, I have:

```
from nose.tools import *
from bin.app import app
from tests.tools import assert_response
```

When I try to run `app_tests.py` from outside of the `tests` directory, one level above the test directory inside the `Chippa` directory, like so:

```
python tests/app_tests.py
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/app_tests.py", line 3, in <module>
    from bin.app import app
ImportError: No module named bin.app
```

But I do have an empty `__init__.py` in the `bin` directory, which I thought would have prevented this issue. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

For that import to work, you have to actually be running a proper module in the first place. So, rather than

```
python tests/app_tests.py
```

, try

```
python -m tests.app_tests
```

Comment: Tried  `python -m test.app_tests ` and got:  `python -m test.app_tests
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named test.app_tests `

Comment: @SeanJarp: Er, `tests.app_tests`, sorry.

Comment: @minitech can you please explain what is the difference between the two commands? I often get import errors and either it is solved by "-m" or using `from __future__ import absolute_import` (most often when using `scrapy` - the web crawling framework). It would be great if you suggest me some good read over how import works or anything that can get me to avoid such errors.